# Ghostscript and pxlcolor: how to generate additional PJL entries in generated PCL

Tags: ghostscript, printer-control-language, pjl

I have to set the Outbin in a PCL file that is generated via Ghostscript with the device=pxlcolor. I'm looking araund but didn't find the necessary parameter.
Can someone pls advice?
My commandline on windows is:

```
C:/Programme/gs/gs9.06/bin/gswin32c.exe -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pxlcolor -dFIXEDMEDIA -dMediaPosition=4 -dDuplex=true -sOutputFile=output.pcl -f Input.pdf
```

That produces a pcl file that takes it sheet(s) from the correct input tray/PaperSource.

Answer (score 1):

There is no provision for this, you will have to add these manually after the file is generated.